# AIX OS startup - setting up rd#.d

Tags: unix, aix, init, inittab

If I already have an entry in /etc/rc.d/rc2.d with a file S99abc, and if I need to execute another script, then what should my file name convention be ? can it be S99def ? how do I ensure that S99abc is executed first before S99def ? any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are executed in ABC-order, eg S98abc before S99def. Usually they are symlinks to the actual scripts, eg:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/*httpd*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root system /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/K08httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root system /etc/rc.d/rc2.d/S92httpd -> ../init.d/httpd
```

Also usually the same script is called at start and stop, eg:

```
$ cat /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd 
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
start)
    /usr/local/sbin/apachectl start
    ;;

stop)
    /usr/local/sbin/apachectl stop
    ;;

status)
    /usr/local/sbin/apachectl status
    ;;

*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|status)"
    ;;
esac
```